# IF statement to decide if a stored proc should execute

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, if-statement

I have a stored procedure that updates a table and then triggers a stored procedure, i'm trying to build in a IF clause to condition when the proc's trigger. For example

```
IF recordType = 4 then do nothing else EXEC usp_procedure
```

I've googled a few examples on if's but cant work the syntax out.

Comment: What is RecordType, a variable, a column, how are you getting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand properly, you're missing `BEGIN...END`

```
IF (recordType = 4)
  BEGIN
    print('do nothing')
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    EXEC usp_procedure
END
```

Comment: The comment-only above ("--do nothing") will give an error... but you could do something that has no effect on results... like "PRINT 'Nothing to do' ".

Comment: @Doug_Ivison, I'm just highlighting that the BEGIN...END was missing. I will update for clarity.